# T-SQL help in getting the row count, column count and size of each table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch the *table name*, *number of rows*, *number of columns* and *size of table*. I have written this stored procedure but I am not getting the correct row count:

```
ALTER PROC abc (@table_name VARCHAR(30))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT t.NAME
        ,count(c.column_id) AS no_of_cols
        ,count(*)
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN Sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE t.NAME = @table_name
    GROUP BY t.NAME
END
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You could join to the `sysindexes` table to give a row count:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE abc (@table_name SYSNAME)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
    t.name, 
    count(c.column_id) AS no_of_cols, 
    MAX(i.rows) AS no_of_rows
FROM 
    sys.tables t

    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id

    INNER JOIN sysindexes i 
    ON i.id = t.object_id    
WHERE 
    t.name = @table_name    
GROUP BY 
    t.name;

END
```

N.B. This method looks at table statistics and could potentially be inaccurate. You can rebuild stats using `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(db) WITH COUNT_ROWS`.

Answer (score 1):

That should help you:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE abc (@TableName SYSNAME)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SizeTable Table
(
name Varchar(100),
rows bigint,
reserved Varchar(30),
data Varchar(30),
index_size Varchar(30),
unused Varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @SizeTable EXEC sp_spaceused @TableName

;With cteColumns as 
(
    select COUNT(*) as ColumnsCount from sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
)

SELECT * FROM @SizeTable as st
CROSS JOIN cteColumns
END
```